# Confusion about Type I Error and Sample Size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, type-i-and-ii-errors

A candy company claims that its lollipops have an average weight of 23 grams. A statistician is suspicious of this claim (believing the average weight to be lower than 23 grams) and decides to conduct hypothesis testing at an alpha level of 5%. The statistician randomly samples 50 lollipops, computes the sample mean as 21.5 grams, and obtains a p-value of 0.07. Which of the following is a correct statement in the context of this problem?

A.) Assuming the null hypothesis is true, the probability of obtaining a sample mean less than or equal to 21.5 grams is 0.05.

B.) The statistician has sufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis.

C.) The statistician could have reduced the probability of committing a Type I error by sampling 200 lollipops instead of 50.

D.) The probability that the average weight of the lollipops is less than 23 grams is 7%.

E.) None Of The Above

My Logic: As you select your alpha level a priori, the answer should be E.) None Of The Above. Your alpha level shouldn't change based on an increased sample size. However, the given answer is C. Can someone kindly explain to me why the statistician could have reduced the probability of committing a Type I error by sampling 200 lollipops instead of 50 (e.g. the alpha level by sampling a greater number of lollipops)?

Edit: Based on my comment below, I suppose since by working with a larger sample size, the statistician has the flexbility of choosing a smaller alpha level, thereby reducing the probability of committing a Type I error. It's not so much that increasing the sample size reduced the probability of committing a Type I error. It's more of since the statistician works with a larger sample size (e.g. 50 vs 200), they can now opt to lower their alpha level. And as an (implicit) result of lowering their alpha, their Type I error rate decreases, hence the statistician could have reduced the probability of committing a Type I error by utilizing larger sampling (sampling from a larger sample).

Thus, answer choice C makes the most sense.

Comment: I suppose since by working with a larger sample size, the statistician has the flexbility of choosing a smaller alpha level, thereby reducing the probability of committing a Type I error. It's not so much that increasing the sample size reduced the probability of committing a Type I error. It's more of since the statistician works with a larger sample size (e.g. 50 vs 200), they can now opt to lower their alpha. And as a result of lowering their alpha, their Type I error rate decreases, hence the statistician could have reduced the probability of committing a Type I error with larger sampling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your choice of "E.) None Of The Above" looks good to me, as does your comment about the larger sample giving the statistician freedom to choose a lower threshold for rejection of the null hypothesis. Other than that, a larger sample does not reduce the risk of falsely rejecting a true null hypothesis.

You will probably find this question and its answers relevant and helpful: [Can I trust a significant result of a t-test if the sample size is small?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265871/can-i-trust-a-significant-result-of-a-t-test-if-the-sample-size-is-small/266041#266041)

Comment: Sanjoy wanted to point out that his logic led him to choice C rather than E that I noted in my answer. That choice would not be correct because the mechanism of reducing the type I error rate with a larger sample size noted by Sanjoy is actually available when planning a new study with a small sample size. The correct option is E.